# Vulkan standard validation layer vs core validation layer

Tags: vulkan

I am learning vulkan and found interesting thing: on my home pc I have `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` layer but on my work pc I don't have it but have `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` instead. What is the difference between them and what should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the table in the [layer documentation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.13.0/windows/layers.html):

> `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` 
>   validate the descriptor set,
>   pipeline state, and dynamic state; validate the interfaces between
>   SPIR-V modules and the graphics pipeline; track and validate GPU
>   memory and its binding to objects and command buffers

And then just after the table of layers:

> In addition to the above individually specified layers, a built-in
>   meta-layer definition has been provided which simplifies validation
>   for applications. Specifying this short-hand layer definition will
>   load a standard set of validation layers in the optimal order:
>
> ```
>  VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation
> ```

In some (early) versions of the VulkanSDK releases, `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` and `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation`, were added (but, not the same version). You should probably just update to latest SDK releases (or at least a later and consistent) version on all your machines.